# problem while deploying app in to ipod

Tags: iphone

This problem is showing after i upgraded my ipod OS to 4.0 . But still i use iPhone SDK 3.1.3 
When i try to deploy app build in iPhone SDK 3.1.3 to my iPod its showing me the error

Error Starting Executable
No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected.

How can i get rid of this problem. should i downgrade my iPod OS to 3.1.3.

Comment: Is your iPod provisioned as a development device? Even if you believe so, follow the directions again to verify that it is. Does it show up green in Organizer when it's connected? or is it red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think you need to use xCode 3.2.3 and configure the base SDK to Device 4.0 in order to install the application to your iPod. As I know, you can not downgrade to 3.1.3 once you upgraded to 4.0.